# How to make a transparent status and navigation bar solid again?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-statusbar

I've made the status and navigation bar go transparent, like so:

```
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
```

This works perfectly! But then, when a certain button is tapped, I want it go back to a solid color again with:

```
    window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white)
    window.navigationBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white)
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR or SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR
```

But the status bar still shows as transparent, is this working for other people? Or am I just doing something wrong on my part? And help would be really appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You are setting the flag for the main window. Then when you press a button you want it to change color from transparent. In your code you never set set the flag back to be shown. Notice the first code… you should have the same code with the status color and decorview.. right now your just doing everything with the still enabled windows.setFlag… think of if statements. If button is pressed change to that.. else stay transparent.. you need to revert the flag that was set when the button was pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear the window flags on button click like this.

```
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
```